# trying to create a group of users from a flat file every has to be done using the package

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

this main problem is to try to get the sql loader to execute inside the package.

```
procedure addGroup
    is
      num number;
      name1 Varchar2(20);
      load Varchar2(200);
    begin
     load := 'host sqlldr kevonia_workspace/pass123 control = C:\Users\Kevonia\Desktop\DBA\usernames.ctl log = C:\Users\Kevonia\Desktop\DBA\usernames.log';
     Execute immediate(load);

    for num in  1..10
    loop 
      select username into name1 from loaded where userid=num;
      DBA_PACKAGE.NewUser(name1);
      dbms_output.put_line(name1|| ': was added' );
    end loop;
    end addGroup;
```

ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Comment: `host` is an SQL*Plus client command; it has no meaning in SQL or PL/SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options

1. Create [external
   table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm).
   You can then manipulate the table as you would for a normal table.
   This is the best option.
2. If you don`t have privileges to create a table and you insist on using host commands look at
   [this](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/8i/shell-commands-from-plsql.php)
   (but really, don't do it).
3. Same as above but using a `dbms_scheduler` executable job.

Comment: still a but new to oracle. can you explain this some now?

Comment: `SqlLoader` is an OS utility by oracle. plsql runs in the database (not the os). To use sqlldr from plsql you need to either execute an os command from plsql which is usually not a good practice but can be done using a java stored procedure (bad), or `dbms_scheduler` executable job (better). The best solution for loading text data into oracle in recent releases is using external tables. check out the link in the original post.

Comment: An external table also seems particularly appropriate here since the data seems to be transitory - doesn't look like it's intended to be kept after the new users are created.